# Cannot access to website after installing cockpit

Tags: iptables, firewalld, networkmanager, cockpit

I have no idea what happened in my system. I have installed `cockpit` then I realize I cannot access to my website, which is hosted in my server, anymore.

Even when I remove `cockpit`, which contains `NetworkManager`, I still cannot access.

There are some info as below. Could anyone give me some advice? Thank you very much.

I disable `firewalld` and replace with `iptables`.

```sh
~ sudo systemctl status firewalld -l
● firewalld.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
~ sudo systemctl status iptables -l
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2021-02-22 00:31:58 +07; 9s ago
  Process: 9785 ExecStop=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11931 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11931 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/iptables.service

Feb 22 00:31:58 ssdnodes-68686 systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 firewall with iptables...
Feb 22 00:31:58 ssdnodes-68686 iptables.init[11931]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Feb 22 00:31:58 ssdnodes-68686 systemd[1]: Started IPv4 firewall with iptables.
~ sudo systemctl status ip6tables -l
● ip6tables.service - IPv6 firewall with ip6tables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ip6tables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2021-02-22 00:32:04 +07; 15s ago
  Process: 9854 ExecStop=/usr/libexec/iptables/ip6tables.init stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11962 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/ip6tables.init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11962 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 22 00:32:04 ssdnodes-68686 systemd[1]: Starting IPv6 firewall with ip6tables...
Feb 22 00:32:04 ssdnodes-68686 systemd[1]: Started IPv6 firewall with ip6tables.
Feb 22 00:32:04 ssdnodes-68686 ip6tables.init[11962]: ip6tables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
```

When list the units with `sudo systemctl list-units` command. There are some info of `iptables` service as bellow.

```sh
  ip6tables.service                                         loaded active exited
  iptables-openvpn.service                                  loaded active exited
  iptables.service                                          loaded active exited
  mariadb.service                                           loaded active running
  network.service                                           loaded active exited
  nginx.service                                             loaded active running
  openvpn-server@server.service                             loaded active running
● openvpn@server.service                                    loaded failed failed
  php-fpm.service                                           loaded active running
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The problem seems to be that they can't access their web site. The way to address the problem starts with the error they receive when accessing it, using `firewall-cmd` to check whether the relevant ports are open, and whether the web server is actually running and listening on those ports. Then depnding on the results of that, checking the web server logs, possibly checking on any backends, and/or using `tcpdump` to find out if traffic arrives at that server at all and how it is handled.

Comment: My `firewall-cmd` suggestion doesn't apply because `firewalld` is masked and therefore not running. Is that expected? If yes, whatever other firewall solution must be checked. If not, unmask it.

Comment: I cannot access to my website and cannot use any my VPN like `openvpn` or `wireguard`. I don't know what I should check now.